# How to Store Android Pictures to Prevent User Deletion but Still Give User Access

Tags: android, file, imageview, android-camera, storage

I'm working on my first real Android application, and I have run into a use case problem for which I cannot seem to find a best practice. The application has a main screen with a RecyclerView that has an ImageView as part of the view that makes up the individual list items. Clicking on an item in the RecyclerView takes you to an Activity with a ViewPager giving details for the selected item and allowing the user to swipe through the details of the items that were displayed in the RecyclerView. As part of the workflow of adding or editing an item, the user can take a picture that is used for generating the thumbnail for the RecyclerView and for display in the details fragment in the ViewPager. I plan to provide the ability for the user to share the detail entry, including the picture, on social media or email or to their Google Photos. My dilema is how the picture should be stored on the user's device. You can store to the public external storage, which is scanned by the media scanner and can be accessed by the user for copying to their computer or sharing.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
```

However, the user can also delete the pictures stored there which poses a problem for generating thumbnails and display in the detail fragment.

Another approach would be to store the pictures to the applications internal storage, like so:

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "DemoFile.jpg");
```

Of course, this would protect the pictures from being deleted. However, the user would not be able to access that storage location from their computer or from other photo apps on their device.

I could store a copy in both locations. However, that seems like a waste of device space. Are there any best practices for such a use case? Do others have any experience with this scenario that they would be willing to share?

Comment: I don't know if it does exist, but is there a way you can "register" with the media scanner that could "expose" your privately-stored images to the media scanner but the user wouldn't be able to delete them?

Comment: "However, the user can also delete the pictures stored there which poses a problem for generating thumbnails and display in the detail fragment" -- so? It is the user's device, not yours. If the user wishes to delete these files, that is the user's choice, not yours. "this would protect the pictures from being deleted" -- strictly speaking, that is not true. Any user could click "clear data" for your app in Settings, which wipes out all of your part of internal storage. Also, rooted device users can delete whatever they want.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I'm not trying to prevent the user from being able to delete the pictures per se. I'm trying to be proactive about protecting the user from deleting a picture without understanding that the picture is now not available in their journal entry within the application.

Comment: Then give the user a choice of whether you should put the images on external storage (access from anywhere, but if the user moves or deletes the file, *c'est la vie*) or internal storage (only accessible from your app, but resistant to accidental deletion).

Answer (score 0):

You could place an empty `.nomedia` file in the folder of your thumbnails. This will prevent the media scanner from scanning what's inside.

That being said, if you'd like to get these thumbnails automatically deleted when your app gets uninstalled, which I think is what you'd want, you can [create a private directory on your external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles) that will be tied to your particular application.

By the way, in Android the user is the application itself, so by making a directory private, you're making it private for the application itself (not the actual user of the device). But obviously, if you're saving these thumbnails on a removable sdcard, or if the actual user roots his device, these files won't truly be private.

Comment: "you can create a private directory on your external storage that will be tied to your particular application" -- that is only "private" insofar as it does not collide with anything else. Any app can still read it (though subject to needing `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` on Android 4.4 through 5.1) and write to it (though subject to needing `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`).

Comment: In my use case, I'm not trying to prevent the user from being able to access these pictures. I tend to think that the user might want them for uses beyond what my app provides. I'm simply to trying to find the best way to allow the user to have access and yet protect their journal entry in the application. If they delete or move the picture, it will no longer be available within the application. The user may not understand that consequence. So, I'm trying to be proactive and protect their journal entry.

Comment: "I tend to think that the user might want them for uses beyond what my app provides." So allow them to explicitly share/export/duplicate those pictures for other apps.  It will be safer that way and potentially less of a nuisance for the actual user.  Personally, I don't like it when my gallery app picks up all the public image folders I have on my external storage. It clutters everything. Plus, it doesn't make me comfortable completely handing off my device to someone else to show them a particular picture in my gallery, since that other person may start looking through all of its folders.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, that's actually an interesting hybrid solution that I had not considered. By default, images could go to private internal storage, but if a user wants a particular image, then they could "share" it to public storage, which would simply make a copy there.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be, to upload the picture the User takes to a server via a small .php script, so it is guranteed, that the user cannot simply delete the picture and causing your app to malfunction, while still giving the user the ability to have a local copy of the image(s) on their device.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm independently writing this application. So, I don't have the resources to provide server storage of the users data. So, I'm using SQLite on the device for data and the device file system for file persistence. At one point, I did do some searching for free cloud storage for this purpose, but I was not able to find anything. Do you know of one that freely provides a database backend or at least image storage?